# LogCoshLoss on pytorch

Tags: loss-function

Hi I am currently testing multiple loss on my code using `PyTorch`, but when I stumbled on `log cosh` loss function I did not find any resources on the `PyTorch` documentation unlike Tensor flow which have as build-in function
is it excite in Pytorch with different name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the pytroch is not found in pytorch but you can build on your own
or you can read this [GitHub](https://github.com/tuantle/regression-losses-pytorch?fbclid=IwAR3R5cEsY_dFknBvCP4hHXXxx67WiM9BmRZbY6B55GhXfzjpDpQlEeNH9Tg) which has multiple loss functions

```
class LogCoshLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, y_t, y_prime_t):
        ey_t = y_t - y_prime_t
        return T.mean(T.log(T.cosh(ey_t + 1e-12)))
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer results in loss values of infinity when there is a large error between the true and predicted values. Here is a numerically stable version:

```
def log_cosh_loss(y_pred: torch.Tensor, y_true: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    def _log_cosh(x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return x + torch.nn.functional.softplus(-2. * x) - math.log(2.0)
    return torch.mean(_log_cosh(y_pred - y_true))

class LogCoshLoss(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(
        self, y_pred: torch.Tensor, y_true: torch.Tensor
    ) -> torch.Tensor:
        return log_cosh_loss(y_pred, y_true)
```

#### Why current answer isn't stable

The accepted answer doesn't work when the error term is very large because `torch.cosh` will go to infinity very quickly. For instance, here is the output of a script where I printed out the values of `torch.cosh(x)` and `torch.log(torch.cosh(x))`:

```
x: cosh: torch.cosh(x), log: torch.log(torch.cosh(x))
1: cosh: tensor([1.5431]), log: tensor([0.4338])
...
9: cosh: tensor([4051.5420]), log: tensor([8.3069])
...
49: cosh: tensor([9.5367e+20]), log: tensor([48.3069])
...
89: cosh: tensor([2.2448e+38]), log: tensor([88.3069])
90: cosh: tensor([inf]), log: tensor([inf])
```

This is running on a CPU and results will likely vary, but it shows that even for small inputs (~90), the result of `T.log(T.cosh())` will go to infinity.

Also of note is that in the torch docs for [cosh](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cosh.html), they state:

> When input is on the CPU, the implementation of torch.cosh may use the
> Sleef library, which rounds very large results to infinity or negative
> infinity. See here for details.

#### Derivation of improved implementation

I looked at the [source for Tensorflow's LogCoshLoss](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.6.0/keras/losses.py#L1580-L1617) which is numerically stable for large errors (I tested it to see).

They perform the calculation as:

```
def _logcosh(x):
    return x + tf.math.softplus(-2. * x) - tf.cast(
        tf.math.log(2.), x.dtype)
        
return backend.mean(_logcosh(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

They use `softplus`, which Torch also has an equivalent of in `torch.nn.functional.softplus`. In the [docs for SoftPlus](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softplus.html), Torch states that:

> For numerical stability the implementation reverts to the linear function when $input \times \beta > threshold$.

#### Extra: why SoftPlus is differentiable

They are able to work around replacing values not being differentiable by writing a custom backward kernel for softplus [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0e8c3c51d9a2a0d364f2707d4131ab12229dc826/aten/src/ATen/native/cpu/Activation.cpp#L500-L520). Notably, for the case where the input is a scalar (the simpler case), they calculate the gradient as:

```
scalar_t z = std::exp(b * beta);
return (b * beta) > threshold ? a : a * z / (z + scalar_t(1.));
```

By computing the gradient this way, they are able to work around the operation of replacing values above the threshold not being differentiable.

Comment: aside: this problem with `torch.cosh` happens even on gpu, contrary to the current documentation